# How does palingenetic fusion occur in rock?

Tags: geology, minerals, terminology

As far as [charnockites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charnockite) are concerned, granitic charnockites are formed due to palingenetic fusion and [metasomatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasomatism), while granulitic charnockites are formed due to high grade [metamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphism).

---

When I googled for palingenetic fusion, I haven't gotten any clear vision.

Can anyone help me to grab the answer for my question?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen the term "palingenetic fusion" anywhere in the geological literature, but seeing that it [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palingenesis):

> Palingenesis is a concept of rebirth or re-creation, used in various contexts in philosophy, theology, politics, and biology. Its meaning stems from Greek palin, meaning again, and genesis, meaning birth.

And seeing that it is used to describe granitic charnockites, I think it is safe to say it is a very obscure term for [anatexis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatexis), a common process of granite formation by partial melting of pre-existing rock. This is most commonly used in high grade metamorphic rocks, and in the context of formation of migmatites and leucogranites.

Comment: You could use the Oxford Geological Reference, which supports your post: "The partial or complete melting of pre-existing rocks to generate new *magma." http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199653065.013.6071